# How to convert data in txt form into a list in python

Tags: python, list, split

For example this is my data in `txt` file:

```
Chair
Table
Planks
Door
```

Each separated by a new line.
So how do I convert it into a `list` so that it's output would be like this:

```py
['Chair', 'Table', 'Planks', 'Door']
```

Every time I try to convert it into a `list`, it's new line character getting printed in the `list` as well.

I tried this code by new line character keeps adding

```
for line in filen:
    setn.add(line)
for items in setn:
    items.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: What code were you using to get the incorrect answer?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain what happened

Answer (score 4):

You need to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#open) the file, then [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) it's contents:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read().split())
```

```
['Chair', 'Table', 'Planks', 'Door']
```

---

**Edit**

Your original attempt was adding the entire `line`. You needed to [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) or [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) each `line`. Because each `line` has a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#:%7E:text=10-,%5Cn,-Microsoft%20Windows%2C) (`\n`) character at the end.

```py
setn = set()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as filen:
    for line in filen:
        setn.add(line.rstrip())

print(setn)
```

```
{'Chair', 'Planks', 'Table', 'Door'}
```

Note that `set` has no duplicates, and to convert a `set` to a `list` you just use `list(set)`

And you can simplify the code down to a generator comprehension if you'd like:

```py
with open('test.txt', 'r') as filen:
    setn = set(x.rstrip() for x in filen)
```

> List comprehensions (similar to generator comprehensions) - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try the python [split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) method.

```
your_list.split("\n")
```

Comment: Better to use `split()` without any arguments. That will take into account multiple spaces, newlines, tabs and all other forms of whitespace.

Comment: Do you mean `your_string` instead of `your_list`?

Answer (score 0):

```
a="""
Chair
Table
Planks
Door
"""
```

**with newline character**

```
print([i for i in a.split('\n')])
output - ['', 'Chair', 'Table', 'Planks', 'Door', '']
```

**without newline character (avoid newline charecter)**

```
print([i for i in a.split('\n') if i != ""])
output - ['Chair', 'Table', 'Planks', 'Door']
```

Answer (score 0):

opening the file in read mode

```
 my_file = open("file1.txt", "r")
```

reading the file

```
 data = my_file.read()
```

replacing end splitting the text
when the newline ('\n') is seen.

```
data_into_list = data.split("\n")
print(data_into_list)
my_file.close()
```

output :

['Chair', 'Table', 'Planks', 'Door']